# Learning PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql

What's the best place to start learning PostgreSQL administration and programming in a Linux environment?  What websites are the most recommended, concise and have easy to learn tutorials?

I am already familiar with ANSI SQL from playing with SQL Server and MySQL; however, I've never touched PostgreSQL before. Any direction you can give is appreciated.

Answer (score 15):

I have found the [documentation on the web](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/index.html) for postgresql to be *very* high quality.

Comment: yea, i'm using that now.  I was hoping there were other websites or blogs people frequently go back to.

Comment: Official link for all manuals (HTML and PDF): http://www.postgresql.org/docs/manuals/

Answer (score 13):

Having gone through this exact process about a year ago I found the following useful:

1. psql prompt is your friend.
2. The [postgres online docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/index.html) are great.
3. [This postgres book was great](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672327562) for both admin and programing for postgres driven programs.

Answer (score 1):

best way to learn to admin a database is to download it, install it, and start it up and work through the problems/questions as they happen.

download from: http://www.postgresql.org/

Once you have it up and running, pick a topic to learn and read up on that one topic.  Move from topic to topic, until you can do everything you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL documentation mentioned above is very comprehensive.
Additionally you can find many PostgreSQL related blog posts on [Planet PostgreSQL](http://planet.postgresql.org)

Answer (score 0):

The PostgreSQL [mailing lists](http://www.postgresql.org/community/lists/) are superb, particularly pgsql-general; they provide a level of help and support that couldn't be bought for any money.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend this e-book [link](http://www.commandprompt.com/ppbook/?page=ppbook), it covers all the topic from sql to pl/pqsql

Comment: I wouldn't - "Copyright © 2001-2002 by Commandprompt, Inc"

Comment: Could you elaborate, @MilenA.Radev ? It your objection because it's dated or because it's not from a reputable publisher?

Comment: @msanford "Dated" is a very mild way to put it.